Next.js App Router Dynamic Routes Cached or not?
The docs for app router are confusing: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#data-cache
It says:

Static routes are cached by default, whereas dynamic routes are rendered at request time, and not cached.
This diagram shows the difference between statically and dynamically rendered routes, with cached and uncached data:

The diagram then shows a dynamic route being cached?

It is showing a dynamic route being cached on client side. In my app there does not seem to be a "router cache", every nav back and forth to a link refetches the RSC payload.
